# "Could not find schema information for the element..." in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I am trying to validate a GXL XML Validator.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE gxl SYSTEM "http://www.gupro.de/GXL/gxl-1.0.dtd">
<!-- attributes 05.02.2002  -->
<gxl xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <graph id="attributes-instance">
        <type xlink:href="../../../schema/gxl/attributes/attributesSchema.gxl#attributesSchema"/>
        <node id="p">
            <type xlink:href="../../../schema/gxl/attributes/attributesSchema.gxl#Prog"/>
            <attr name="file">
                <seq>
                    <string>Ric</string>
                    <string>Andy</string>
                    <string>Susan</string>
                    <string>Andreas</string>
                </seq>
            </attr>
        </node>
    </graph>
</gxl>
```

When I put it through the online Parser [Validome](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/) it states that the document is valid with no warnings or errors. However when I put it through a C# XML Validator, the file is still valid, but I get  the following warnings.

```
Warning: Line: 4, Position: 2 "Could not find schema information for the element 'gxl'."
Warning: Line: 5, Position: 3 "Could not find schema information for the element 'graph'."
Warning: Line: 5, Position: 9 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'id'."
Warning: Line: 75, Position: 2 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'edgeids'."
Warning: Line: 76, Position: 2 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'hypergraph'."
Warning: Line: 77, Position: 2 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'edgemode'."
Warning: Line: 6, Position: 4 "Could not find schema information for the element 'type'."
Warning: Line: 6, Position: 9 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink:href'."
Warning: Line: 67, Position: 2 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink:type'."
Warning: Line: 7, Position: 4 "Could not find schema information for the element 'node'."
Warning: Line: 7, Position: 9 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'id'."
Warning: Line: 8, Position: 5 "Could not find schema information for the element 'type'."
Warning: Line: 8, Position: 10 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink:href'."
Warning: Line: 67, Position: 2 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink:type'."
Warning: Line: 9, Position: 5 "Could not find schema information for the element 'attr'."
Warning: Line: 9, Position: 10 "Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'."
Warning: Line: 10, Position: 6 "Could not find schema information for the element 'seq'."
Warning: Line: 11, Position: 7 "Could not find schema information for the element 'string'."
Warning: Line: 12, Position: 7 "Could not find schema information for the element 'string'."
Warning: Line: 13, Position: 7 "Could not find schema information for the element 'string'."
Warning: Line: 14, Position: 7 "Could not find schema information for the element 'string'."
Validatoin Complete:Valid XMLFile
```

Is there anyway to tell if both validators are producing the same warnings just that Validome is not reporting it or is there something different between the validators.

Also why would “Could not find schema information for the element..."  be a warning and not a more severe error wouldn't you need the schema information to have a useful XML document?

The C# Validator

```
 // Set the validation settings.
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints;


        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

        // Create the XmlReader object.
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);

        try
        {
            // Parse the file. 
            while (reader.Read()) ;
            if (isValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Validatoin Complete:Valid XMLFile");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Validatoin Complete: Not a Valid XMLFile");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Xml.XmlException e)
        {
            //Displays any parsing errors
            Console.WriteLine("Parsing error:" + e.Message);
            isValid = false;
        }

  // Display any warnings, general errors, and validation errors .
    // If there are only warnings an xmldocument is still valid
    private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
         if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Warning: " + String.Format("Line: {0}, Position: {1} \"{2}\"",
                args.Exception.LineNumber, args.Exception.LinePosition,
args.Exception.Message));
        }
        else if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + String.Format("Line: {0}, Position: {1} \"{2}\"",
                args.Exception.LineNumber, args.Exception.LinePosition,
args.Exception.Message));
            isValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validation error: " + args.Message);
            isValid = false;
        }

    }
  }
```